# Dirichlet problem: Obtaining the harmonic measure through Riesz representation theorem

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions, riesz-representation-theorem

For the [Dirichlet problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_measure#Definition) on a bounded open domain $D \subset \Bbb R^n$
$$
\Delta u=0, \text{ on } D, \\
\left. u\right|_{\partial D}=f \in C\left( \partial D\right).
$$
With a fix $x$ in $D$, an application of the Riesz representation theorem gives 
$$
u(x)=\int_{\partial D} f(t) d\mu_x(t),
$$
for some measure $\mu_x$.

What is the operator on which Riesz theorem is applied?
Which Riesz [theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem) is used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This assumes that the Dirichlet problem is solvable for all continuous $f$ (which means that each boundary point admits a barrier). Now, if you fix a point $x\in\Omega$, and look at the value $u(x)$, then clearly $P_x:f\mapsto u(x)$ is linear, and by the maximum principle it is positive, and
$$
|u(x)| \leq  \|f\|_{C(\partial\Omega)},
$$
so $P_x$ is a bounded linear functional on the space of continuous functions on the boundary. Finally, by the Riesz representation theorem, there exists a measure $\mu_x$ that represents $P_x$.