# Proving that The sum of two strongly convex functions is strongly convex

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

> Assume that $f$ is $a$-strongly convex and $g$ is $b$-strongly convex. Is the sum $f+g$ strongly convex, and with what constant?

**Definition:** $f$ is $a$-strongly convex if 
$$ f(x)-f(y) \le \left<f '(x),x-y\right>-\frac{a}{2}\|x-y\|^2$$
for all $x,y$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241308/dirichlet-problem-obtaining-the-harmonic-measure-through-riesz-representation-t

Answer (score 2):

This is totally pretty easy from your definition we have

$$f(x)-f(y) \le \left<f '(x),x-y\right>-\frac{a}{2}\|x-y\|^2$$
and 
$$g(x)-g(y) \le \left<g '(x),x-y\right>-\frac{b}{2}\|x-y\|^2$$

summing up both inequality we obtain:
$$f(x) +g(x)-f(y)+g(y) \le\left<f '(x),x-y\right> +\left<g '(x),x-y\right>\\-\frac{a}{2}\|x-y\|^2-\frac{b}{2}\|x-y\|^2$$

that is $$(f+g)(x)-(f+g)(y) \le\left<(f +g)'(x),x-y\right> +\left<g '(x),x-y\right>-\frac{a+b}{2}\|x-y\|^2.$$

Hence $f+g$ is $a+b$-strongly convex

Answer (score 1):

c-strongly convex, c>=a+b

proof:

f(x+y)>=f(x)+f'(x)y+f''(x)/2 *y^2

g(x+y)>=g(x)+g'(x)y+g''(x)/2 *y^2

where f' is the first order gradient, g' is the first order gradient, f''(x) is some positive number at least a, g''(x) is some positive number at least b, both of them depend on x,

adding them together, we have F(x)=f(x)+g(x)

F(x+y)>=F(x)+F'(x)y+F''(x)/2 *y^2

where F'=f'+g' is the gradient of F
F''=f''+g''>=a+b
based on the strongly convex definition, F is c strongly convex

c=a+b if f'' and g'' have the same min location
c>a+b if f'' and g'' have different min location.

First time to use this website, can i use latex here?